# Getting MSOL users through REST API for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, sharepoint-2013, office365, azure-active-directory

I'm looking for a REST call to get all MS-Online users.

I am able to get these users through the following Powershell command

Get-MSOLUser -All

I am currently using `http://{siteurl}/_api/web/siteusers` call to fetch users, but this doesn't return all users that I get using Powershell.

Is there a way I could get all those users?

**NOTE:**  One thing that I have noted is that */siteusers* call doesn't return those users who haven't created a personal site(Onedrive) or in other words, returns only those users who have a */personal/user_name_domain_com* site.

Could this be the reason why */siteusers* call is not returning this data while Powershell is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself! The trick is to use Graph API. Refer to  [Azure Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn151678.aspx)  for users.

Get an access token for "https://graph.windows.net" resource. This access token can then be used to access https://graph.windows.net

**Url to hit**

- *https://graph.windows.net/yourdomain/users?api-version=2013-04-05*

Domain should be something like  ***abc.onmicrosoft.com***

**Headers**

- Content-Type : application/json;odata=verbose **Note::**(application/json will do)
- Authorization : Bearer eYrvwvZ_PN9Ty5a2pQrb23y******